# Do we have $\int_M \mathcal L_X\omega=0$ for $m$-form $\omega$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

Let $M$ be an oriented $m$-manifold without boundary, $X\in \mathfrak X(M)$ be a vector field, and $\omega \in \Omega^m_c(M)$ be a compactly supported top-degree differential form.

**Question**: Do we always have
$$\int_M \mathcal L_X\omega=0,$$
where $\mathcal L_X$ is the Lie derivative?

**Motivation**: The integration operation has a diffeomorphism invariance, i.e., if $F:M\to M$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism, then
$$\int_M \omega = \int_M F^*\omega.$$
Now, suppose that the diffeomorphism $F$ is infinitesimal, i.e., $F$ maps each $p\in M$ to a point that is infinitesimally separated from $p$. Such infinitesimal diffeomorphism can be heuristically represented by a vector field $X\in \mathfrak X(M)$, which is an 'arrow' from $p$ to $F(p)$.

Furthermore, the infinitesimal version of the pullback $F^*\omega$ is the Lie derivative $\mathcal L_X\omega$. Hence, I suspect that the infinitesimal statement of the diffeomorphism invariance of integral should be
$$\int_M \mathcal L_X\omega=0.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\intprod{\mathbin{\lrcorner}}$
Consider the [Cartan magic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_formula)
$$\mathcal{L}_X\omega = X\intprod(d\omega) + d(X\intprod \omega),$$
where $d$ is the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) and $X\intprod \omega$ is the [interior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product) of $X$ and $\omega$.

For a top-degree form $d\omega=0$, so we conclude by [Stokes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes%27_theorem) that
$$\int_M \mathcal{L}_X\omega = \int_M d(X\intprod \omega) = \int_{\partial M}X\intprod \omega = 0$$
since the manifold $M$ has no boundary.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your simple and elegant answer!